# How to add pre-receive hooks in Gitlab >= 15.11

Tags: gitlab, githooks, gitaly

Im trying to add a pre-receive-hook to a gitlab repository.
I have access to the instance as an administrator and the gitlab version is 16.x. so it is > 15.11.

So I was following [Set server hooks for a repository, GitLab 15.11 and later](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html?tab=GitLab+15.11+and+later), I need to use gitaly-cli to add the hook archive to the repository (Step 2).
But this is where I am stuck. I cannot find any documentation how to do it, nor how to setup the gitaly-client or where to get it.

Has anyone done this before and can shed some light to that for me? Most of the threads I found are to old and are not targeting gitlab 15.11.